# url split and join for each element _ JavaScript

Tags: javascript

suppose we have this URL "/user/id" .

```
let url = "/user/id"
```

so I need to split this urls and make an individual url . somethig like this:

```
["/", "/user", "/user/id"]
```

I can split this with **.split("/")**.I think I need some **forEach()** after spliting but I cant get it right.

Comment: Please provide the code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is way easier if you use `indexOf` to find the slashes and `.slice` to get the parts:

```
 const result = ["/"];
  let pos = 1;

 while(true) {
   pos = url.indexOf("/", pos + 1);
   if(pos < 0) break;
   result.push(url.slice(0, pos + 1));
 } 

 result.push(url);
```

Or the "functional approach" would be:

```
 url.split("/").map((_, i, arr) => arr.slice(0, i + 1).join("/") || "/");
```

Comment: why haven't you used directly `while(pos >= 0)` instead of a `break`?

Comment: Well I could use that and do `(pos + 1) || url.length`, but I prefer the more readable version.

Comment: If it works, that's the most important I guess, but it reminds me my BASIC years, with such things as `GOTO` :D I would probably used `split` and a basic for loop for that though

Answer (score 1):

For-loop solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/c9asnfw4/1/

```
let url = '/user/id', 
    result = ['/'],
    parts = url.split('/'); 

for(let i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) { // Skip first /
    const part = parts[i];

    if(i === 1) { // Start slash is already existing
        result.push(result[i-1] + part);
    } else if(i > 1) {
        result.push(result[i-1] + '/' + part);
    }
}
```

**Output**

> (3) ["/", "/user", "/user/id"]

---

**EDIT**: Slightly shortened:

```
let url = '/user/id', 
    result = ['/'],
    parts = url.split('/'); 

for(let i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) { // Skip first /
    result.push( (result[i-1]) + (i > 1 ? '/' : '') + parts[i] );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c9asnfw4/2/